# Zip command -ksh zip not found error

Tags: linux, unix, zip, compression

I have a folder structure like

```
/home/abc/Image/
```

In this folder i have to one more folder Blob and one txt file Worker.txt

I want to zip blob folder and Worker.txt into one file (Worker_image.zip)
For this i am using :

```
  zip -r Worker_image.zip Blob Worker.txt
```

I am using SSH Tectia Client for Unix and this command is not working.
It is giving an error :

```
-ksh : zip not found
```

This same command is working in putty

Comment: Can you try using `tar` if its available ?

Comment: i can use gzip but do you know how do i combine the two folders to one by gzip and then rename to zip ?

Comment: Am afraid `zip` is not an AIX supplied command by default. You could use `compress` or install a GNU or other zip tool

Comment: tar will create .tar file. and i want .zip extension file

Comment: You will need to compile and install [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/)'s zip. This may have already been done for your system, so you may just need to download it. Google is your friend.